# Trying to trigger a Post Confirmation Lambda trigger shows error in var aws = require('aws-sdk');

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

Here is my code to make a folder in an s3 bucket when a user verifies his email and then the POST confirmation lambda triggers the function to make the folder in an s3 bucket.

As a newbie in AWS lambda, the code shows the error, Below is my Code.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
if (event.request.userAttributes.email) {
    put0bjectToS3('documenthandle', event.request.userAttributes.email + "/");
    console.log(" should have posted");
}
else {
    context.done(null, event);
}    
};    
function putObjectToS3(bucket, key){
console.log("got to put0bjectToS3 code");
var params = {
    Bucket : bucket,
    Key : key
};    

console.log("got past params");
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log("got to put code");
    if (err) console.log("some error happened");
    else {
        console.log(" successful") ;
        context.done(null, event) ;

    }
});
```

}
It shows the error like

```
Response:
{
"errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line           1)",
"errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
"stackTrace": [
"  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 1\n    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');\n"
]
}
```

please suggest me a solution for it and also give me any suggestions with respect to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to confirm which runtime your Lambda function is using? The function code is written in node.js, but Lambda is reporting that it's expecting a Python function. 
[image: Lambda runtime]

[(see the available Lambda runtimes for details)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)